# Add Agar.io to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get agar.io to show up in an HTML page without any errors. I already have the page and the `<iframe>` set up but agar.io is not showing. How do I make agar.io show up?

Comment: How, exactly, are you trying to do this?

Comment: `$(function(){
                $("#agario").load("http://agar.io/index.html"); 
});`

Comment: We're going to need MUCH more than that if you want someone to try to help you.

Comment: Added JSFiddle to question, should help a bit.

Comment: What relation does a file server have to all desribed here?

Comment: This isn't being used on a web server, I am calling file://.

Comment: The code you showed us does address `file://` in any place. Also you're trying to load a whole site into a div not iframe

Comment: I "uploaded" it to jsfiddle but I am on my file system not a TCP/IP server.

Comment: And agar.io still doesn't load in an iframe.

Comment: I think this a classic case of asking something about a solution instead of describing initial problem... can you describe what you're trying to do and existing schema?

Comment: you're not looking at this right. You need to be able to control `agar.io` in order to be able to allow cors for it. You don't set cors headers on the site that is receiving information, you set them on the site that is providing them. Unless you control 'agar.io', which I'm guessing you don't, you cannot use it for CORS

Comment: Also, headers are the one and only way to enable CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agar.io authors definitely don't want their site to be used in a third party. As far as their content is interactive, not static, you can't do anything with it. They do a top-level redirect, you can't hold them inside an iframe